# Is there an edition of Gibbon's *Decline and Fall* that has been annotated by a modern historian?

Tags: ancient-rome

I like reading old history texts. I also like knowing accurate history (to the degree that we know it). Is there an edition (abridged or not) of *The History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire* that includes notes on what Gibbon got wrong, or information he didn't have access to?

Alternately, is there a separate text that would accomplish the same end?

Comment: Why limit your search to reeditions of Gibbon? I would also be searching for original works (journal articles or books) that criticize his work.

Comment: Not a bad point, but an annotation would be easier than going back and forth between two books. Do you know of a good example of what you suggest?

Comment: No, I haven't done the research. One way to ask about it on this site would be along the lines of "What about Gibbon's account have  other historians disputed?".

Comment: @Calion. Nice question. I was wondering about the same when I read him, and the best I got was investigating individual points from the books. I tried a few quick searches right now as I know 'The Peloponnesian War' has a few modern copies, but there does not seem to have been the same level of interest in Gibbon. It could, perhaps, be a bit too monumental for people to take on in the same way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

<sup>*Source: [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0307700763)*</sup>

**Suggestion** (not necessarily a valid Answer since I do not own a copy of this edition and cannot verify to what extent it is annotated with modern information) have you investigated [this edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0307700763) from Hugh Trevor-Roper (pub 1993, this edition is a 2010 reprint)? Some of the customer reviews indicate it has factual corrections, such as this:

> The merit of Gibbon's masterpiece needs no defense. Readers are, I assume, looking for remarks about whether this Everyman set is a quality edition. Well, this is it. I looked at the Folio Society edition: lovely, yes; but fragile and grossly overpriced. The Everyman is sturdily bound with solid boards and paper. The typeface is clean. A handy bookmark is bound into each volume. It's nice to hold in the hand.
>
> The text is the standard one of 1910, **with notes to catch major errors of fact; there are good, more recent introductions** (to vols 1 and 4) by the eminent Hugh Trevor-Roper (does that man know everything, or what?). ALL of the original footnotes are here, and readers of Gibbon should consider them as essential. Someone once quipped that Gibbon lived out his sex life in footnotes; there's some truth in that remark. [*emphasis added*]

Edit by OP: This is indeed an excellent edition for this purpose. Here's an example, from page 4:
[image: example of textual correction]

Note however that the corrections are from no later than 1936; for more up-to-date information, the book refers readers to the enormous and exorbitant Cambridge [Ancient](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/classical-studies/ancient-history/cambridge-ancient-history-2nd-edition?format=WX) and [Medieval](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/history/european-history-1000-1450/new-cambridge-medieval-history-1?format=WX&isbn=9781107568914) Histories ("which contain detailed bibliographies").

Comment: @axsvl77 the notes are not 1910, the original work is 1910.  Hugh Trevor-Roper (Jan 15 1914 - Jan 26 2003)  published this in 1993.  This particular edition is a 2010 reprint of the 1993 work.  If that is not modern enough, I don't know what is.

Comment: Maybe add that to your answer?

Comment: @axsvl77 well anyone looking for works by modern historians should be familiar with Hugh Trevor-Roper but perhaps not.

Comment: I have this set of books and yes it does have pretty decent modern annotations.

Comment: It looks like the reviewer complaining about typos was referring to a Kindle edition; that is, not this (Everyman) edition at all. I had heard that this was the definitive edition, but *not* that it had annotations correcting Gibbon's errors. I could wish for something cheaper, but that's not what I asked for. Thanks!

Comment: @Calion - I would suggest looking for thiss edition in a public library to see if its modern annotations meet your expectations (in quantity and quality) before investing in a set for yourself.  Alternatively, Half Price Books (or Amazon Used copies) might be a cheaper way to acquire a set.

Comment: @KerryL I managed to get it given to me as a wedding gift!! Luckily it is exactly what I was looking for, and a beautiful edition to boot.

Comment: @Calion that is fantastic!  Congratulations on both the wedding and the gift!